# Filtering Lucene query results based on external data

Tags: java, lucene

I need to apply a custom filter to make sure that the user who executed the search has permissions to view the documents are returned by the searcher. I have extended simpleCollector. However, in the Java Docs recommend against using both indexSearch and Reader:

> Note: This is called in an inner search loop. For good search performance, implementations of this method should not call IndexSearcher.doc(int) or org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.document(int) on every hit. Doing so can slow searches by an order of magnitude or more.

I need to get the documents to get the id term and check those against data held in the DB. Is there another way to filter the results other then using a collector?
Is there a more efficient way of obtaining documents without calling indexSearcher?

My code currently is the following:

```
public class PermittedResultsCollector extends SimpleCollector {
    private IndexSearcher searcher;

    public PermittedResultsCollector(IndexSearcher searcher) {
        this.searcher = searcher;
    }

    public boolean needsScores() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
        Document document = searcher.doc(doc);
        if (callToExternalService(document.get("id"))){
            throw new CollectionTerminatedException();
        }
    }

    public IndexSearcher getSearcher() {
        return searcher;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, if you want to use a value for sorting, scoring, faceting or filtering like this, it should be a [DocValues](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/10/27/introducing-lucene-index-doc-values/) field.  However, if you are calling an external database in the same place, that's probably going to have a bigger impact on performance than a call to `searcher.doc`, anyway.